# Recommended way to measure http requests

Tags: metrics, open-telemetry

From the [OTel Metrics specification](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/3e380e249f60c3a5f68746f5e84d10195ba41a79/specification/metrics/api.md#counter) Counter is the recommended instrument to measure the number of requests completed. This can later be used to calculate the throughput rate.

> Example uses for Counter:
>
> - count the number of bytes received
> - count the number of requests completed

However, [OTel's semantic conventions](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/metrics/semantic_conventions/http-metrics.md) do not include a metric for such a use case, with `http.server.active_requests` being the closest thing.

| Name | Instrument | Unit | Unit (UCUM) | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `http.server.active_requests` | Asynchronous UpDownCounter | requests | `{requests}` | measures the number of concurrent HTTP requests that are currently in-flight |

Granted, the Metrics Semantic Conventions are still "Experimental", but this seems like such a basic use case which is even mentioned in the API spec.

My questions are:

- Is the counting of requests via a counter not recommended?
- What is the best way to monitor throughput?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not a spec creator but the number of requests is indeed a typical example for counters and is therefore recommended ubiquitously, e.g. check [Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter).

Why is it not stated in the semantic conventions spec - hard to say. But yes it is very experimental, there are [400+ issues](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/issues) in the whole thing and you may create another one :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is not in the spec for now, I would infer from other usages and guidelines that it should be

1. `http.server.request.count` or
2. `http.server.requests`

I prefer #1 as I think it is much clearer, but #2 seems to lean closer to the name of the `active_requests` metric.

Looking at the [RPC Conventions](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/semantic_conventions/rpc-metrics/) shows a somewhat similar pattern where `request.something` is used for properties of requests and responses, but pluralized metrics are used for aggregating on the requests/responses themselves, not any of their properties: `rpc.server.requests_per_rpc`, `rpc.server.responses_per_rpc`, `rpc.client.requests_per_rpc`, and `rpc.client.responses_per_rpc`.

Also see the [guidelines for pluralization](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/semantic_conventions/#pluralization).

I would think that these guidelines certainly allow for `http.server.request.count`:

> Pluralization

> Metric names SHOULD NOT be pluralized, unless the value being recorded represents discrete instances of a countable quantity. Generally, the name SHOULD be pluralized only if the unit of the metric in question is a non-unit (like {fault} or {operation}).

> Examples: system.filesystem.utilization, http.server.duration, and system.cpu.time should not be pluralized, even if many data points are recorded. system.paging.faults, system.disk.operations, and system.network.packets should be pluralized, even if only a single data point is recorded.

> Use count Instead of Pluralization

> If the value being recorded represents the count of concepts signified by the namespace then the metric should be named count (within its namespace). The pluralization rule does not apply in this case.

> For example if we have a namespace system.processes which contains all metrics related to the processes then to represent the count of the processes we can have a metric named system.processes.count. The suffix count here indicates that it is the count of system.processes.

As mentioned by other answers, the conventions are not finalized, and if you feel that greater consistency could be achieved, it may be worth trying to contribute to the discussion.